# Instrument Android App with startInstrumentation

Tags: android, android-manifest, instrumentation

I want to instrument my App with the [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) Interface from inside the tested app.
I have a custom activity that every of my activities extend. In that I want to start the instrumentation to get information about the app:

```
public class BxActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    boolean instru = startInstrumentation(new ComponentName(BxActivity.this, InstrumentationRobot.class), null, null);
```

Imho that should restart the app with the instrumentation code in the InstrumentationRobot.class. It is in the same Android project and package.

```
public class InstrumentationRobot extends Instrumentation {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    Log.v("InstrRobot", "Hello from Robot");
    start();
}
```

I've added the instrumentation to the manifest like this:

```
 <instrumentation
        android:name="InstrumentationRobot" (class in the same pkg)
        android:targetPackage="my.package.name" />
</application>
```

This is the correct manifest code for my instrumentation, so my little robot prints out "hello" to me.

Thanks, soeren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution and updated my question with the correct code.
The mistake was in the manifest file.

I deleted the

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

tag and the instrumentation class name must not start with a dot, if in the instrumentation class is in the same package and .apk file as the app itself.

The instrumentation tag must also be a direct child of the manifest.